# Nginx :allow folder access only from localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, nginx

I have a folder named `admin` which is in the `var/www/html` directory.

I want to access that folder from the public internet ie allows access only from localhost.

For that

1) Created a file `whitelist-admin` in the `sites-available` directory and added the following.

```
server{

location ~ /admin/.*\.php$ {
     allow 127.0.0.1;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
     deny all;
  }

}
```

When I access `<public-ip>/admin` I am getting `403` error but the link `<public-ip>/admin/index.php` is working I want to disable it.

Comment: Are there links you need to be accessed from public domains?

Comment: I just want to completely disable access from `admin` folder (allow only localhost access) from public internet

Comment: Then wouldn't a  location ~ ^/admin {  #what you have there} work? I mean, only allow 127.0.0.1 in any link containing /admin, doesn't matter if it ends on .php

Comment: So how can i properly disable the access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
server {

    location = /admin { # its good to block the admin alone too
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ^~ /admin/ { # block anything beginning with /admin/
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; 
        #fastcgi_index index.php; 
        # With php7.0-cgi alone: 
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm: fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
    }

}
```

This configuration should allow only localhost connections, and deny all others on any admin url.

On the other hand, if you ever get blocked from your machine, may be because you are making the request through your public ip instead of directly through localhost.(Ex: if you do a redirection through the internet, your ip will be the server ip, not localhost).

This should do the trick, if it doesn't, maybe there is another location that catches the connection instead that this one. Comment if it works or what is not working.

EDIT:

Source to understand it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

The ^~ will indicate that this is the best "~" on the configuration, it will be the first one to be checked after the "=" locations. This should prioritze your /admin/ location over your .php location.

This should work. (finally :D)

Comment: Its not working  i am able to access `admin/index.php`

Comment: Weird, because it should not, should be a rare interaction with the try_files. try a test, change try_files for a "return 302 www.google.com;" And try to get redirected with an external ip. If you get redirected from an external ip, I'll get my testbench on and try to reproduce your problem and find a solution.

Comment: Strange it's not redirecting I am getting the same result I think the configuration not working

Comment: Then there is 2 possibilities. 1, try files is doing weird things which will need a more specialitzed solution or 2, there is another location block, maybe something catching the .php before it can enter this  admin location block, that allows external connections. Do you have any other configuration that can catch .php or index * ?

Comment: Let me check the config again

Comment: I've the following  in  `default.conf`   `location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #fastcgi_index  index.php; 
  # With php7.0-cgi alone:
  #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  # With php7.0-fpm:
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 }`

Comment: Maybe that's what's taking it. I'll change my configure for prioritzing the admin before te index.

Comment: What was the change in the answer??

Comment: Adding a ^ before ~ ( location ^~ ^/admin/ { ) so the nginx stops checking other rules when this one matches. Also, move this rule to the upper part of all locations, just in case.

Comment: I moved that rule to the top (in the `nginx.conf`) but still the same:)

Comment: Oh god, I'm tthinking on so many possibilities xD. Okay, last try to know if it's the location |.php that gets the connection (which should not be, as it shoudl enter the admin one). "return 302 https://www.google.com;" inside the php location block and comment temorarily the other things on that location. And try to get redirected. if you get redirected we'll now it's that, if not... it's the try_files somehow.

Comment: You mean `try_files return 302 google.com;`  in the `~\.php` location

Comment: no, only "return 302 https://google.com;" in the ~\.php location block. If you get redirected, will mean that the priority is wrong, and it enters the wrong location block. If you don't get redirected, means that the problem is in the "/admin/" location block.

Comment: Yea its redirecting

Comment: Okay, Can you put the \.php location block under the admin one? Like this we'll be sure it catches admin before php. I've edited my post with an example.

Comment: And if you have other server blocks, set it under any location blocks you want to prioritze over this one.

Comment: You might want to add a `allow ::1;` as well, in case your connection is via IPv6 (which is default when using `localhost` for most applications)